# multidimensional array from comma separated string

Tags: php, string, list, multidimensional-array

im trying to convert a comma separated into a multidimensional array to create a menu structure of this.

this is what i have already..

```
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                if($i > 0){
                    array_push($tagmenu[0][$pretags[$i-1]], array($pretags[$i]=>array()));
                } else {
                    array_push($tagmenu, array($pretags[$i]=>array()));
                }

            }
```

i have this as a string

```
$tags = 'image,landscape,night';
```

and i want it to look like this

```
Array(
      [images] = Array (
                 [landscape] = Array(
                               [night] = Array ()
                 )
      )
```

i'm searching my fingers off on this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recursively create a multidimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417019/how-to-recursively-create-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tags = 'image,landscape,night';
$newArray = array();
$wrkArray = &$newArray;

foreach(explode(',',$tags) as $tag) {
    $wrkArray[$tag] = array();
    $wrkArray = &$wrkArray[$tag];
}
unset($wrkArray);
var_dump($newArray);
```