# add list of key's to an multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I'll try to be brief, yet clear.
for example:

```
$foo['test'] = array();
$foo2('test1','test2','test3','test4');
```

is it possible to create some kind of a loop to get this multidimensional array?:

```
$foo['test']['test1']['test2']['test3']['test4'] = ...;
```

You don't know in advance how long the $foo2 array will be.
I hope my question is clear and not to stopid to ask.

Any help is welcome!
thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't imaging the situation where you'd want to do this !

Comment: in a database are different links stored.
a link has a parent based on id's.
link1 => id = 1, parent = 0_
link2 => id = 2, parent = 0_1_.
i'm trying to get $foo[0][1]...   => $foo2 = (0,1,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a valid use-case for this. But you can do this with references (modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1417033/1438393))

```
$foo['test'] = array();
$foo2 = array('test1','test2','test3','test4');

$result = array();
$temp = &$result;

foreach($foo2 as $value) {
    $temp[$value] = array();
    $temp = &$temp[$value];
}
unset($temp);
$foo['test'] = $result;
var_dump($foo);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/136349)

---

A stupid and dumb solution using [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval). **This should not be used.** I'm posting it just for the fun of it ;)

```
$foo2 = array('test1','test2','test3','test4');
eval("\$res['".join("']['",$foo2)."']=[];");
$foo['test'] = $res;
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/136352)

Comment: smart and simple solution :)