# Convert unidimensional array values to keys of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like:

```
$indexes = array('a', 'b', 'c');
```

And a would like to convert it to an multidimensional array like:

```
$array['a']['b']['c']
```

The index quantity is dynamic, i can have 2, 3 or more.

I need to do this convertion and then assign a value to this index. Example:

```
$array['a']['b']['c'] = 'My value';
```

I tried a logic using [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_flip()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php), but it doesn't work. Any help will be welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a Single Array into a multidimensional array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911822/how-to-convert-a-single-array-into-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard, It is a different situation

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677099/php-use-a-string-as-an-array-index-path-to-retreive-a-value

Comment: try this: https://github.com/adael/Fset/blob/master/libs/Fset.php

Comment: @MarcB, There he is trying to retrieve and i am trying to write, but it's a good indication, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an interesting solution based on [an answer posted by @JasonWoof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1417032/999820), it is simple and elegant.

```
$indexes = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$value = 'My value';

while ($indexes) {
    $value = array(array_pop($indexes) => $value);
}

var_dump($value);
```

Shows:

```
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["c"]=>
      string(8) "My value"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$arr = array();
$ref = &$arr;
foreach ($array as $key) {
    $ref[$key] = array();
    $ref = &$ref[$key];
}
$ref = $key;
$array = $arr;
```

Comment: That's what I call `same thought` :-)

Answer (score 1):

try it with an iteration i'd say:

```
<?php
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$target = array();
$current = &$target;
foreach ($array as $k){
  $current[$k] = array();
  $current = &$current[$k];
}
$current = "Hello World";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($target);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Hello World
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: :))) That's what I call same thought

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach

```
function multiDimArray(array $keys, $value) {
    if (count($keys) == 0) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        $key = array_shift($keys);
        return array( $key => multiDimArray($keys, $value));
    }
}

$multiDimArray = multiDimArray(array('a','b','c','d'), "Hello World!");
```